# Difference between AES-CCM and AES-CCM*

Tags: aes, ccm

I'm trying to understand the different between AES-CCM and AES-CCM* (as defined in IEEE Std 802.15.4™‐2011, Annex B).
I see that there are more restrictions on L and M and also M=0 is allowed:

- L = 2
- M = [0,4,8,16]

Is it correct that the max message length is 2^16 = 64K (since L=2)? Isn't it too short?
The encoding of M is quite different since M=0 is allowed. Are there other differences in the calculation?
Is it secure for variable-length messages? How?

Comment: It is clear that you define AES-CCM* as the AES-CCM* defined in 802.15.4. But to which definition of AES-CCM are you referring to ?
Also, can you tell us anything about your doubts on security for variable length messages ?

Answer (score 3):

CCM* as defined by [IEEE Std 802.15.4-2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) is a generalization of CCM as defined by [RFC 3610](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3610). The generalization is that where RFC 3610 allows the tag lengths *M* {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16} which are encoded in a 3-bit field *M'* where the value 0 is reserved, CCM* also allows the tag length *M*=0 and encodes it using the value *M'*=0 in the tag length field.

There are other specifications of CCM with slightly different constraints. For example, NIST allows the 16-byte header to be formatted differently.

The length *L* of the message length field can range from 2 to 8. There is no difference between RFC 3610 and CCM* in this respect.

Allowing a zero-length tag makes CCM* a dual-family algorithm: CCM* with a non-empty tag is an AEAD algorithm, but CCM* with an empty tag is an unauthenticated cipher.

CCM* *as used in the 802.15.4 LR-WPAN protocol* has additional restrictions which are enumerated in §B.3.2 of IEEE Std 802.15.4-2011: that the underlying block cipher is AES, that the plaintext length is encoded in 2 bytes, and that the authentication tag length is one of {0, 4, 8, 16}. These restrictions only apply to the use in 802.15.4, not to CCM* in general.

Since the plaintext length is encoded in 2 bytes, the plaintext cannot be more than 65535 bytes long. This limitation would be too restrictive for some applications, but it's perfectly fine for a 802.15.4 frame, which is limited by the underlying physical transport. The maximum size depends on the transport, and I don't know what the highest-capacity transport is, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4#The_MAC_layer) states that “most IEEE 802.15.4 PHYs only support frames of up to 127 bytes”.

(Similarly [RFC 5116](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5116#section-5.3) specifies a 12-byte nonce for CCM, meaning L=3, which is fine for the TLS protocol since its record size field itself is a 3-octet field.)

As for security, 802.15.4 §B.4.3 discusses it, and I'll just summarize the relevant points here. The [original security proof for CCM](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-36492-7_7.pdf) assumes a fixed tag length for a given key. CCM* allows the use of different tag lengths with the same key, which has a known weakness ([Rogaway and Wagner, *A Critique of CCM*, §3.4](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/070)). CCM* avoids this weakness by ensuring that the encryption mask depends on the authentication tag length (which the general definition of CCM doesn't mandate, but RFC 3610 and CCM* do).

Comment: Thanks for directing me towards Rogaway & Wagner's critique of CCM. It pulls no punches: "This paragraph [from the CCM spec] is so far from saying something technically accurate that we wouldn’t know where to begin."